# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'go'

Tags: python, windows

have strange problem to cant know it . I will be thankful to help me .......[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5kly.png)

Comment: You entered `go` into your program's `input` call, and it doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You've to enter integers to convert it to int. You cannot convert "hi" to integer for example. What will be the value of int("hi")? For sure it'll give error. Try adding integers as input. If you're confused, take input in integer format only by writing `varodi=int(input(":"))` and take 1 as input to break the loop. Change the statement to `if varodi==1:` then break. Or else just put the input as integer

Comment: @Ya-Heydar-Karar did the answer help you?? If yes, try to accept it. Not only in my case, also in future, if the answer was found useful, accept it